# ¿Cómo puedo omitir opciones de un select con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, json

Buenos días mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo un botón "agregar" que al dar *click* me adiciona un `<select>` y un `<input>`.

Lo que quiero es que al seleccionar una opción del `<select>` se omita en el próximo,es decir que no se incluya las opciones ya seleccionadas en los anteriores `<select>` en el nuevo selector que se generé al hacer *click* al botón agregar.

Por otra parte para cada `<select>` se agrega un botón que elimina toda la fila, de modo que la opción seleccionada de dicho `<select>` debería poder estar nuevamente disponible al eliminarse.

Este es el json de prueba.

tipoDepreciacion.json

```
[
    {
        "id_sub_catalogo":"1",
        "descripcion_breve":"AMORTIZACION DE SOFTWARE"
    },
    {
        "id_sub_catalogo":"2",
        "descripcion_breve":"DA DEPREC.DE EQUIPO DE COMPUTO"
    },
    {
        "id_sub_catalogo":"3",
        "descripcion_breve":"DEPREC.DE EQUIPO DE COMPUTO"
    },
    {
        "id_sub_catalogo":"4",
        "descripcion_breve":"DEPREC.DE EQUIPOS DIVERSOS"
    },
    {
        "id_sub_catalogo":"5",
        "descripcion_breve":"DEPREC.DE INFRAESTRUCTURA"
    },
    {
        "id_sub_catalogo":"6",
        "descripcion_breve":"DEPREC.DE MUEB.Y ENSERES"
    },
    {
        "id_sub_catalogo":"7",
        "descripcion_breve":"DA DEPRECIACION ASIGNADA"
    }
]
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            metodos.botonAgregar();
            metodos.botonEliminarInput();            
});

var metodos = function(){
            return {
                botonAgregar:function(){
                    $("#btnAgregar").click(function(){
                        metodos.cargaCombo();
                    });
                },
                botonEliminarInput:function(){
                    $("body").on("click",".delete",function(){
                        $(this).parent("div").remove();
                    });
                },
                cargaCombo:function(){
                    $.ajax({
                            url: 'tipoDepreciacion.json',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            type: 'GET',
                            success: function (json) {
                                var items = document.getElementById("items");
                                //items.innerHTML += "";
                                var select = `
                                        <div class="form-row dep_val" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                                                <select class="idDepreciacion">
                                        `;
                                for (let valor of json) {
                                    select += "<option value='" + valor.id_sub_catalogo + "'>" + valor.descripcion_breve + "</option>";
                                }
                                var html = select + `</select> &nbsp;
                                                    <input class="form-control col-md-2 valor" type="number" required/>  &nbsp;     
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary delete">-</button>
                                                    </div>`;
                                $("#items").append(html);

                            }
                    });
                }

            }
        }();
```

En la imagen siguiente no debería incluirse la opción seleccionada del primer `<select>` en el segundo `<select>`(debería omitirse).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el evento *onchage*  del primer select debes modificar el segundo select, ocultando esa opción. Supongo que cada opción se identifica por un dato igual en ambos select, sea el value, el id u otro. Ya tienes la idea, ahora inténtalo y dinos si lo lograste o tienes alguna dificultad.

Comment: le agradecería saber como hacerlo ya que soy nuevo en jquery y javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que funcione como quieres necesitas primero una variable donde guardes los indices ya seleccionados, luego ir agregando los indices a la variable para que no se tomen en cuenta el agregar un nuevo `<select>`.

Te sugiero que una vez seleccionado el valor de un `<select>` y se haga click en agregar, que dicho elemento se deshabilite para evitar el dilema de tener que modificar el próximo si se cambia el valor del actual (veo que no tienen `name`, solo `class` así que imagino que obtienes sus valores con *jquery*).

Luego debes controlar que no se puedan agregar mas de los necesarios (7).

Todo lo anterior lo haces modificando la función `botonAgregar` de esta forma:

```
botonAgregar:function(){
  $("#btnAgregar").click(function(){
    if(seleccionados.length<6){
      var valor = $('select:enabled').val()
      valor !=null ? seleccionados.push(valor) : null
      $('.idDepreciacion').prop('disabled', true);
      metodos.cargaCombo();
    }
  });
},
```

y agregando esta linea al recorrer el *json* para insertar los `<option>`

```
if(!seleccionados.includes(valor.id_sub_catalogo))
```

Luego respecto al la función eliminar, debes modificarla de la siguiente forma (ya que no los elementos no cuentan con `id` deben obtenerse con otros métodos):

```
$("body").on("click",".delete",function(){
  let padre = $(this).parent("div"); 
  let val=padre.children('select').val();
  seleccionados=seleccionados.filter(n => n!=val)
  padre.remove();  
  if($('select:enabled').val()!=null){
    var last = [...$('.dep_val')].pop();
    var valor = $(last).find('.valor').val();
    last.remove();
    $("#btnAgregar").click();
    var last = [...$('.dep_val')].pop()
    $(last).find('.valor').val(valor);
  }
  $("#btnAgregar").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Ademas de que para conservar el valor del ultimo input numérico debes obtenerlo antes y pasarlo al nuevo input que se creará (eso lo hace el código dentro el `ìf`).

Por ultimo te recomiendo que el boton de agregar se deshabilite al llegar al máximo.

Aquí puedes ver una demostración de como funcionaria, luego puedes descomentar las lineas ajax:

```js
var seleccionados=[];

$(document).ready(function() {
    metodos.botonAgregar();
    metodos.botonEliminarInput();            
});

var metodos = function(){
  return {
    botonAgregar:function(){
      $("#btnAgregar").click(function(){
        if(seleccionados.length<7){
          var valor = $('select:enabled').val()
          valor !=null ? seleccionados.push(valor) : null
          $('.idDepreciacion').prop('disabled', true);
          metodos.cargaCombo();
        }
        if(seleccionados.length==6)
          $("#btnAgregar").prop('disabled', true);
      });
    },
    botonEliminarInput:function(){
      $("body").on("click",".delete",function(){
        let padre = $(this).parent("div"); 
        let val=padre.children('select').val();
        seleccionados=seleccionados.filter(n => n!=val)
        padre.remove();  
        if($('select:enabled').val()!=null){
          var last = [...$('.dep_val')].pop();
          var valor = $(last).find('.valor').val();
          last.remove();
          $("#btnAgregar").click();
          var last = [...$('.dep_val')].pop()
          $(last).find('.valor').val(valor);
        }
        $("#btnAgregar").prop('disabled', false);
      });
    },
    cargaCombo:function(){
      /*$.ajax({
        url: 'tipoDepreciacion.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (json) {*/
          json=JSON.parse('[{"id_sub_catalogo":"1","descripcion_breve":"AMORTIZACION DE SOFTWARE"},{"id_sub_catalogo":"2","descripcion_breve":"DA DEPREC.DE EQUIPO DE COMPUTO"},{"id_sub_catalogo":"3","descripcion_breve":"DEPREC.DE EQUIPO DE COMPUTO"},{"id_sub_catalogo":"4","descripcion_breve":"DEPREC.DE EQUIPOS DIVERSOS"},{"id_sub_catalogo":"5","descripcion_breve":"DEPREC.DE INFRAESTRUCTURA"},{"id_sub_catalogo":"6","descripcion_breve":"DEPREC.DE MUEB.Y ENSERES"},{"id_sub_catalogo":"7","descripcion_breve":"DA DEPRECIACION ASIGNADA"}]');
          var items = document.getElementById("items");

          var select = `
          <div class="form-row dep_val" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
          <select class="idDepreciacion">
          `;
          for (let valor of json) {
            if(!seleccionados.includes(valor.id_sub_catalogo))
            select += "<option value='" + valor.id_sub_catalogo + "'>" + valor.descripcion_breve + "</option>";
          }
          var html = select + `</select> &nbsp;
          <input class="form-control col-md-2 valor" type="number" required/>  &nbsp;     
          <button class="btn btn-primary delete">-</button>
          </div>`;
          $("#items").append(html);
        /*}
      });*/
    }
  }
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAgregar">Agregar</button>
<div id="items">
</div>
```

Y así el código funciona como esperas, saludos.

Comment: estimado muy buena su respuesta pero si yo elimino un campo debería seguir los componentes que no se han seleccionado y además de ello uso el ajax ya que esa data la traigo desde desde la base de datos y pasa a un controlador en .net

Comment: el archivo json solo lo creo como muestra de que datos esta llenando el select pero realmente los llamo desde el controlador en .net con conexión a base de datos

Comment: @Dum, Hola la respuesta que da **the-breaker** es una respuesta que contesta tu duda, y lo que preguntas en tu **pregunta** la cual es `¿Cómo puedo ocultar una opción de mi select con javascript?`

Comment: @Dum el código es solo de ejemplo, puedes comentar la linea del json y descomentar las lineas de ajax y funcionará. Por otra parte puedo agregar la parte de eliminar los elementos y que vuelvan a ser seleccionables..

Comment: te lo agradecería ya que mi campos dinámicos cuentan con un botón eliminar y de ser así tendría que cargarse el select siguiente con el option que se elimino

Comment: Estimado @the-breaker como sería cuando se elimine un fila para que se recargue el selector con las opciones.

Comment: Uff @Dum me costo algo de trabajo ya que los elementos no contaban con `id`, tuve que usar solo jquery, pero ya esta la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Muchas gracias @the-breaker

Comment: Estimado @the-breaker solo tengo una duda cuando cargo mi datatable en el $(document).ready(function(){ metodos.carga_tabla();metodos.botonAgregar();}) la función que me ayudaste deja de funcionar y cuando omito el método de carga_tabla() funciona bien, además de ello el datatable funciona bien.

Comment: @Dum tal vez podamos ver el problema en otra pregunta para no hacer esta mas extensa, debo ver cuales son los motivos por los que debes omitir el método y deja de funcionar.

Comment: Estimado @the-breaker en la solución que me brindaste cuando elimino un input por ejemplo de haber creado tres y elimino el de al medio se limpia el valor almacenado en el último input , agradecería que me pudieras ayudar, ya que crear una nueva pregunta tendría que generar todo ese contenido.

Comment: @Dum entiendo puedo revisar esa parte luego, en unas horas voy a estar libre para verlo.

Comment: @Dum actualice la repuesta con tu petición.

Comment: Estimado @the-breaker solo modificaste el método eliminar ya que no logro funcionar ese método.

Comment: @Dum si solo modifique ese método, te sale algún error?

Comment: quite la primera variable last declarada y funciono. Declaraste 2 veces la misma variable.

Comment: estimado @the-breaker como te comente anteriormente ya funciona mi eliminación al quitar la variable last y me genera error en last.remove() pero aun asi funciona

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99921/discussion-between-the-breaker-and-dum).

Comment: Estimado @the-breaker cuando ejecuto tu ejemplo con ajax pasa lo siguiente:cuando elimino un input por ejemplo de haber creado tres y elimino el de al medio se limpia el valor almacenado en el último input, pero probé tu ejemplo sin ajax y funciona a la perfección.

Comment: @Dum lo que deberías hacer para evitar ese problema es obtener el json con ajax solo una vez al principio, en lugar de llamarlo cada vez dentro de la función.

Comment: como podría obtenerlo una sola vez el ajax

Comment: puedes declarar una varable `var json` al principio, luego en la sección de `$(document).ready(function() {` puedes hacer la llamada ajax y colocar el contenido en la variable.